# Google Maps API Javascript v3 smooth panTo

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have done quite a few searches here and there. None of them give satisfactory answer, all we know is Google Maps API v3 has a limitation, that if the panTo target is more than 1 window height/width of the current center, it will not be smooth.

Still, I want to achieve "somewhat" smoother, not just "jumping" to the target.

Here is my solution (not perfect but I think it's better than jumping):

1. Calculate distance between current and target locations
2. Divide into several sections, each section is a little less than one window
3. panTo each section to achieve "sectional" smooth animation.

It's fine to find out each section target by the following algorithm:

- Current is c(x,y)
- Target is t(x,y)
- Section count is s
- Each section is c(x) + (t(x) - c(x)) / s , c(y) + (t(y) - c(y)) / s

Here is the problem: how to calculate the section count?

It should be based on the current zoom level and window size, right?

Ok, I finally come up with some like this and it works (but did not consider the zoom level)

```
            var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(Math.pow(lastLocation.lat() - status.Lat, 2)) + Math.abs(Math.pow(lastLocation.lng() - status.Lng, 2)));
            //console.info('last:' + lastLocation.lat() + ',' + lastLocation.lng());
            //console.info('new:' + status.Lat + ',' + status.Lng);
            //console.info('distance:' + distance);
            var smoothFactor = 8.0 / 1440; //hard code for screen size without considering zoom as well...
            var factor = $(window).width() * smoothFactor;
            smoothPanSections = [];
            var sectionCount = Math.ceil(distance / factor);
            var sectionLat = (status.Lat - lastLocation.lat()) / sectionCount;
            var sectionLng = (status.Lng - lastLocation.lng()) / sectionCount;
            for (var i = 1; i <= sectionCount; i++) {
                if (i < sectionCount) {
                    smoothPanSections.push({ Lat: lastLocation.lat() + sectionLat * i, Lng: lastLocation.lng() + sectionLng * i });
                }
                else
                    smoothPanSections.push({ Lat: status.Lat, Lng: status.Lng });
            }

            panStatus();
```

And the panStatus is:

```
function panStatus() {
    if (smoothPanSections.length > 0) {
        var target = smoothPanSections.shift();
        //still have more sections
        if (smoothPanSections.length > 0) {
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    panStatus();
                }, 100);
            });
        }
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(target.Lat, target.Lng);
        map.panTo(location, zoomSize);
    }
}
```